# jQuery - Getting Correct UserID - AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

so I am at a bit of a bind here. So I have 2 jQuery scripts that handle a simple database row update (per the user ID, session), this lets the user send a "Gift" that adds value to the users database row column "bonus".

I got this working practically perfect, but the problem is: **It will only get the first ID of the results when gifting**, not any other user ID. I suspect this is a fault in the looping logic.

RequestBin tells me I have my correct ID for myself, and the user ID is stuck with the first iterated userid (we cant send to any other user ID). We need to be able to gift any result (user ID).

We use a dialog to trigger the AJAX call with Yes / No. Yes firing the AJAX event, no closing model.

**The AJAX JS - Sends value to database**

```
function ConfirmDialog(message) {
    $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
        .html('<div><h6>' + message + '</h6></div>')
        .dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: 'Gift this user new Gift?',
            zIndex: 10000,
            autoOpen: true,
            width: '600',
            height: '200',
            resizable: false,
            buttons: {
                Yes: function () {
                    $('body').append('<h1>Confirm Dialog Result: <i>Yes</i></h1>');
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    var sender = $('input[name=sender]').val();
                    var receiver = $('input[name=receiver]').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'https://xxxxx.m.pipedream.net',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            sender: sender,
                            receiver: receiver
                        },
                        beforeSend: function () {
                            $('#gift-bonus-status').text('Sending...').delay(100).fadeIn().delay(100).fadeOut();

                        },
                        success: function (response) {
                            $('#gift-bonus-status').text('Gift Sent!').delay(100).fadeIn().delay(100).fadeOut();
                        }
                    });
                },
                No: function () {
                    $('body').append('<h1>Confirm Dialog Result: <i>No</i></h1>');

                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
};
```

```
function fetchTopTransfers() {
    $(function () {});
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/ajax_user_list.php',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {
            var html_to_append = '';
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                $('input[name=receiver]').val(item.user_id);
                html_to_append +=
                    '<div style="float:left"><a href="/details/?id=' + item.product_id + '/"><img src="/images/' + 
                    item.cover + '" style="width:50px;height:75px;margin:5px" /></a></div><a href="/user/?id=' + 
                    item.user_id + '/"><img src="/' + item.avatar + '" style="width:45px;height:45px;border-radius:50%;margin:5px" /></a><div style="float:right;padding:10px;text-align:right"><b>' + 
                    formatBytesProduct(item.speed) + '</b><div style="padding-top:5px;text-align:right"><span class="material-icons" style="vertical-align:middle;color:#C0C0C0">redeem</span> <a onclick="ConfirmDialog(\'Do you wish to gift ' + item.username + ' with gift? This will deduct 70 points from your current balance.\')" id="gift-bonus-status">Give Gift</a></div></div><div style="padding-bottom:5px">' + 
                    item.name + '</div><div style="max-width:235px;margin-left:60px;margin-top:-4px;background:#D3D3D3;border-radius:4px;overflow:auto"><div style="height:15px;width:' + 
                    item.progress + '%;background:#E92324;padding:5px;text-align:center;color:#FFF;border-radius:4px">' + 
                    item.progress + '%</div></div></div><div style="clear:both"></div><input type="hidden" name="sender" value="<?=$account->getId()?>" /><input type="hidden" name="receiver" value="' + 
                    item.user_id + '" />';
            });
            $("#top-transfers").html(html_to_append);
        }
    });
}
fetchTopTransfers();
setInterval(function () {
    fetchTopTransfers()
}, 5000);
```

**AJAX responce:**

What is happening here???

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: where exactly is it going wrong? Is it sending the wrong ID to the server, or receiving the wrong ID back from the server? Or something else? You're talking about a wrong ID but there are several places in your code where IDs are used. Please be more specific.

Comment: There are listed 4 users. Each has a user ID unique. We can only at all times retrieve the First user ID, it ignores the 3 other users in the GET/JSON results

Comment: Ok. How many input boxes with `name=receiver` exist in your page? Because `$('input[name=receiver]').val()` will set the value of _all of them at once_ every time you run that command. is that what is happening? It sets all your inputs to the same ID? You still are being a bit vague about the precise behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: That is exactly what is happening. We have 2 input boxes (nowhere else), in the first JS  function that holds these values, and updates the receiver hidden input with what is received back from AJAX data. Is this a issue with $.each() ?

Comment: No it's an issue with your use of .val(). If I'm not mistaken, you are actually creating these "receiver" inputs during your $.each loop, and you are putting the current user_id into the field already using `<input type="hidden" name="receiver" value="' + item.user_id + '" />`.  So actually I think you can probably just remove the `$('input[name=receiver]').val()` entirely - it doesn't seem to be useful, and actually it seems actively harmful in this situation.

Comment: Thing is, if i do that and remove this value (as well as in data param) - the PHP script doesn't know which user_id to grant the row value towards. That's why I looked at getting this receiver INT over to PHP so i can bind the POST request to the query.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you're saying. All I said was to remove one line of code. This does not remove the ability of the script to set the user ID - like I said, the line `<input type="hidden" name="receiver" value="' + item.user_id + '" />` already sets the correct value.

Comment: i'll repost. The issue is very simple, and maybe screenshots better illustrate what im talking about.

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's simple yes. So did you actually try the simple solution that I suggested? It will take you 1 minute to test it. Just remove this one line of code: `$('input[name=receiver]').val()`. that's all. Please just try it. the answer below is suggesting a fix to your sending code as well, which likely has a similar issue

Comment: P.s. if you want to add screenshots you don't need to repost...just edit your existing question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there many inputs with name `receiver` that's why you are not able to pass correct values. So, inside your `ConfirmDialog` function pass `this` as well it will refer to current element which is clicked. Then , inside your function to get required values you can use `$(this).closest(".outer").find(..)..`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//just for demo..
var data = [{
  "user_id": 1,
  "product_id": 12,
  "username": "acc",
  "name": "swi",
  "progress": "20",
  "speed": 15
}, {
  "user_id": 2,
  "product_id": 12,
  "username": "acc",
  "name": "swi22",
  "progress": "10",
  "speed": 12
}]
var html_to_append = "";
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
  //give outer div.. also pass `this` inside your function
  html_to_append +=
    '<div class="outer"><div style="float:left"><a href="/details/?id=' + item.product_id + '/"><img src="/images/' +
    item.cover + '" style="width:50px;height:75px;margin:5px" /></a></div><a href="/user/?id=' +
    item.user_id + '/"><img src="/' + item.avatar + '" style="width:45px;height:45px;border-radius:50%;margin:5px" /></a><div style="float:right;padding:10px;text-align:right"><b>' +
    (item.speed) + '</b><div style="padding-top:5px;text-align:right"><span class="material-icons" style="vertical-align:middle;color:#C0C0C0">redeem</span> <a onclick="ConfirmDialog(\'Do you wish to gift ' + item.username + ' with gift? This will deduct 70 points from your current balance.\',this)" >Give Gift</a></div></div><div style="padding-bottom:5px">' +
    item.name + '</div><div style="max-width:235px;margin-left:60px;margin-top:-4px;background:#D3D3D3;border-radius:4px;overflow:auto"><div style="height:15px;width:' +
    item.progress + '%;background:#E92324;padding:5px;text-align:center;color:#FFF;border-radius:4px">' +
    item.progress + '%</div></div><div style="clear:both"></div><input type="hidden" name="sender" value="23" /><input type="text" name="receiver" value="' +
    item.user_id + '" /></div>';
});
$("#top-transfers").html(html_to_append);
//add el it refer to `this`
function ConfirmDialog(message, el) {
  $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
    .html('<div><h6>' + message + '</h6></div>')
    .dialog({
      modal: true,
      title: 'Gift this user new Gift?',
      zIndex: 10000,
      autoOpen: true,
      width: '600',
      height: '200',
      resizable: false,
      buttons: {
        Yes: function() {
          $('body').append('<h1>Confirm Dialog Result: <i>Yes</i></h1>');
          $(this).dialog("close");
          //get closest div(outer) then find required inputs values
          var sender = $(el).closest(".outer").find('input[name=sender]').val();
          var receiver = $(el).closest(".outer").find('input[name=receiver]').val();
          console.log("Reciver --" + receiver + " Sender ---" + sender)
          $.ajax({
            url: 'https://xxxxx.m.pipedream.net',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
              sender: sender,
              receiver: receiver
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
 //use el here as well.. 
 $(el).text('Sending...').delay(100).fadeIn().delay(100).fadeOut();

            },
            success: function(response) {
            //use el here as well
              $(el).text('Gift Sent!').delay(100).fadeIn().delay(100).fadeOut();
            }
          });
        },
        No: function() {
          $('body').append('<h1>Confirm Dialog Result: <i>No</i></h1>');

          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      },
      close: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).remove();
      }
    });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<div id="top-transfers">
</div>
```